# Why can't I integrate the volumn of the rotation body of $r=a(1+\cos(\theta))$, rotating about the polar axis, using the side area of a cone？

Tags: calculus, analysis, area

Sorry for making a such long title, I hope the picture below can make up my question more clearly.
It is basically a calculus problem.
[the problem and my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9bxH.png)

The question itself is written in Chinese, but it just asks the same as the title, that is,

rotate the curve $r=a(1+cos(\theta))$ about the polar axis, what is the volumn of the rotation you get?

and I used the conic side area($S = \pi *r *l$) to do the integration only to find a wrong answer($a^2*8/3$) which need to multiply another $a$ to get the correct one.

So what did I miss? Is there a better approach? I am desperite to know!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: What's the polar axis? Is it the line $\{(r,\theta)\,:\,\theta=0\lor \theta=\pi\}$?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is.